# Calculus proof attempt

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Why does
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}\right)\frac{1}{\dot{x}}$$

not yield the same result as

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\right)    \ \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}\    $$

Algebraically, they seem identical and yet with the lower one I am unable to prove the theorem.

Comment: Are the $\frac{1}{\dot{x}}$ and $\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$ outside the derivative in each case?

Comment: is this a hint or a question?

Comment: Use the quotient rule for both. In the first one, you will see $y''$ and $x''$; in the second one, only $x''$ would appear.

Comment: I think they are...

Comment: Please, you should learn elementary calculus before claiming that some expressions are identical. In the first we have a derivative of $\dot{y}/\dot{x}$ with respect to $t$, in the second a derivative of $1/\dot{x}$ with respect to $t$. If you think, that's all the same you have no clue about calculus and have to study it before trying to solve such questions.

Comment: yes unfortunately quite a beginner

Comment: One has to say the truth about the understanding of calculus of the OP. If he thinks that these two different things are the same, he *needs* to study elementary calculus before continuing. Elsewhere he will go nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

$f'=\frac{d}{dt}f$ is a function, the derivative of $f$. You can not move arguments in and out of the function. In general $f'(g(t))\ne g(t)f'(t)$ if that is what you believe.

To evaluate the first you can use the quotient rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}\right)=\frac{f'(t)g(t)-f(t)g'(t)}{(g(t))^2}$$
For the second you can use that $1/f(t)=(f(t))^{-1}$ and use the chain rule (or you can use the quotient rule) to get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac1{f(t)}\right)=-\frac{f'(t)}{(f(t))^2}.$$

These expressions are definitely not identical in general.